# I need to infinitely rotate a view until told to stop

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, rotation

There are so many posts similar to this that I have seen and none of them works.

Here is my code so far.

```
func startRotating(view : UIImageView, rotating : Bool) {

    //Rotating the rotatingClockBarImage
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {

        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    }, completion: {finished in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {

            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)

        }, completion: nil)
    })//End of rotation

    continueRotating(view: view)

}
```

The original problem would be that I couldn't rotate a full 360 degrees. I figured that out by rotating half way and the other half in the completion.

The problem now is once this animation finishes, that's it. I have tried putting it in a while loop, for loop, calling two similar functions back and forth. Nothing works it just keeps freezing my app.

In a for loop, for example, that would run 3 times, I put a print(). The print writes to the console three times but the animation only happens once. Because of this I am thinking the animation is just cutting itself off before it even starts, and the final rotation is the only one that plays through. So I need to find a way to allow it to play each rotation through.

This shouldn't be that hard seeing that Apple had their planes rotate so easily in a former version of Xcode in a game app. I'm trying to avoid deleting and reinstalling the old version just so I can look at that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it would be more easy:

```
   extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }

    func stopRotating(){
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        //or
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Then for rotating:
yourView.rotate360Degrees()

for stopping:
yourView. stopRotating()

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "layer" part. I basically copied and pasted your code to my program and tried to fit it all in to work but i get the error "ViewController has no member 'layer'". And because of this i am also getting an error when trying to call it. when i write 'myView'.rotate360Degrees() it has an error saying "UIImageView has no member 'rotate360Degrees'".

Comment: its an extension, what u need to do is paste all the code outside your class. Then your use it like imageView.rotate() ..

Comment: so I copied and pasted your code outside of the class. (in between my imports and my class) and it says "use of unresolved identifier 'self'". Sorry if these are obvious questions, i'm still getting used to this. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: no prob buddy, do one thing create any empty swift file named Extensions.swift. Paste all code there but remember one thing import UIKit

Comment: ok so i did that but i am still getting the same error with 'self'. I even tried removing import Foundation, same errors though.

Comment: can you share screenshot here of the code as well as of Extension Class

Comment: I did it but it added it to my question. not this discussion. you should see it though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142612/discussion-between-ankit-and-adriangutierrez).

Comment: what you are missing is wrapping up it in extension UIView {}. paste all code that I wrote above in extensions class.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try calling startRotating again in the completion block of your second half turn ?

Note that you should do that conditionally with a "stop" flag of your own if you ver want it to stop.

Comment: yeah i tried that and actually i ended up finding out a way to continuously get it to loop the way i was going but it just got faster and faster until the app would eventually freeze.